# python pool worker using >100%

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I set up a pool of 10 workers for python multiprocessing, after start the process one of the process uses 900% of the CPU. Is there a way to limit the CPU usage that each pool worker uses while multiprocessing?

Comment: couple more details: I am running on  a MAC and using python 2.7

Comment: I may not be the problem with Python muliprocessing; It could be problem with your code specific to that thread which may be busy running some job.

Comment: why do you even need multiprocess if one process is already using 900% of the CPU? what do you hope to gain? why not run them all in order and have each one take up 900% till the whole thing is done?

Comment: I found it was an update for a function that was using the 900% of the CPU. I was using numpy.dot first, but that was changed to numpy.tensordot and that was taking all the CPU. Maybe numpy.tensordot uses internally something different for the multiplication that forces the CPU to use all avaialbel resources.

Comment: Also, the 900% process was very inefficient, it was not 9 times faster than a 100% process